# Book Suggestion for Approximating Integrals using Random Partitions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, reference-request, numerical-methods

Suppose I want to approximate the integral $\int_0^1 x^2\,dx$ using Riemann Sums or Darboux sums over **random** partitions of the interval $[0,1]$, Like in the image below:[image: Approximating the are under the curve y=x^2 using random paritition of the interval 0,1]

Here, A *"random"* *partition* of $[0,1]$ containing $16$ partition points,

$$P=\{0, 0.048499, 0.097571, 0.25324, 0.28515, 0.4087, 0.45946, 0.53824,  0.62423     0.67352, 0.72305, 0.84254, 0.85201, 0.87255, 0.91006, 1\}$$

was created randomly with corresponding lower Darboux sum (showed in red) = $0.292536$ and upper Darboux sum (showed in blue) = $0.377436$, And we've got an approximation of  $\int_0^1 x^2\,dx = \frac{1}{3} = 0.333333\ldots$

Which Books or other resources do you suggest to read that treats rigourously problems like this, Both theoretical (Just the mathematical theory used to address such problems) and practical (Approximating integrals on a computer in such manner)?

There are some challenges I was thinking about that need addressing:

**First**, What is a **random partition**? It needs to be rigorously defined...

**Second**, What about partitions that their points are distributed according to other probability distributions such as the Gaussian distribution or others, And how can we know which probability distribution will give the best result (probabilistically) to approximate an integral?

**Third**, How can we answer questions such as, *"What is the probability that the approximated value of the integral is within $0.5$ from the exact value of the integral?"*, i.e. How can we calculate probabilities like $$P\left\{\int_0^1 x^2 \,dx - 0.5 < \text{LOWER SUM}<\int_0^1 x^2\,dx < \text{UPPER SUM} < \int_0^1 x^2\,dx + 0.5\right\} \text{?}$$

Thanks...

Comment: One specifies a random partition by specifying its probability distribution. The simplest example that comes to mind is: First choose an i.i.d. sample of size $n,$ each observation being uniformly distributed in $[0,1],$ then sort it into increasing order.

Comment: There is of course a bit of redundancy in that last expression; one can write $$P\left\{\int_0^1 x^2 \,dx - 0.5 < \text{LOWER SUM} < \text{UPPER SUM} < \int_0^1 x^2\,dx + 0.5\right\}$$ and it says the same thing.

Comment: This number $0.5$ is so big that one would seldom avoid being at least that close.

Comment: I think with a sorting of an i.i.d. from a uniform distribution this might admit a neat closed-form solution.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for the comments, I’ve used 0.5 just as an example to show what kind of questions we may ask. I didn’t mean in any way that I am going to actually check bounds on the integral by using 0.5, I’ve  Just asked wether there is some theory that enables us to answer questions like that...